# Phonegap DateTime Picker plugin compatible with platforms Android,Ios and Windows Phone

Tags: phonegap-plugins, datetimepicker

Could you please suggest me  any Phonegap DateTime Picker plugin  that is compatible with platforms Android,Ios and Windows Phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have number of plugins avail for datepicker, As I tried this already, I would recommend you to follow below steps to make it work,

**Step 1:** Run the following command

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/mrfoh/cordova-datepicker-plugin
```

**Step 2:** Handle the click

```
$('.nativedatepicker').focus(function(event) {
    var currentField = $(this);
    var myNewDate = Date.parse(currentField.val()) || new Date();

    // Same handling for iPhone and Android
    window.plugins.datePicker.show({
        date : myNewDate,
        mode : 'date', // date or time or blank for both
        allowOldDates : true
    }, function(returnDate) {
        var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
        currentField.val(newDate.toString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));

        // This fixes the problem you mention at the bottom of this script with it not working a second/third time around, because it is in focus.
        currentField.blur();
    });
});

$('.nativetimepicker').focus(function(event) {
    var currentField = $(this);
    var time = currentField.val();
    var myNewTime = new Date();

    myNewTime.setHours(time.substr(0, 2));
    myNewTime.setMinutes(time.substr(3, 2));

    // Same handling for iPhone and Android
    plugins.datePicker.show({
        date : myNewTime,
        mode : 'time', // date or time or blank for both
        allowOldDates : true
    }, function(returnDate) {
      // returnDate is generated by .toLocaleString() in Java so it will be relative to the current time zone
        var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
        currentField.val(newDate.toString("HH:mm"));

        currentField.blur();
    });
});
```

**Step 3:** You may need to convert the result of date.parse() back to an object to get the picker to work a second or third time around. If so, try inserting this code after the myNewDate declaration:

```
if(typeof myNewDate === "number"){ myNewDate = new Date (myNewDate); }
```

Comment: Hi..Could you please post complete example ??

Comment: i am using windows phonegap 3.4 please tell me the steps

Comment: I am using cordova 3.5 for windows phone 8. It is not workding for windows 8. In fact, "org.apache.cordova.plugin.datepicker/src" only shows android source code. @KarthikManoharan Have you tried it successfully?