# DatePicke and TimePicker in Phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

I m developing an android application in phonegap . I have to add DatePicker and a timePicker. That's why i find and follwed this tutorial https://github.com/native5/cordova-android-plugins , there is no much instructions so i found this tutorial for the same plugin (DatePicker and timePicker) http://bikasv.com/blog/2013/04/14/cordova-datepicker/ . 
I followed step 1 which say:

1/- Just copy datePickerPlugin.js file to your ‘www’ folder. Create a package com.bikasv.plugins.datepicker and put DatePickerPlugin.java file into this package. Now update your res/xml/config.xml with following lines –

but i m bloqued in step 2. I don't know where to copy the DatePicker Function and TimePicker  Function . in which file in my project.

Or is there a more simple solution to have a DatePicker and TimePicker in my Android phonegap Application

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272980/phonegap-datetime-picker-plugin-compatible-with-platforms-android-ios-and-window

Answer (score 0):

If you use a recent version of Apache Cordova you don't have to copy any files at all. Just run

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/native5/cordova-android-plugins.git
```

in the root directory of your project. Then you can use the plugin as described in the examples of the plugin.